How to resolve external crate module conflicts between [dependencies] and [dev-dependencies]
I'm getting unresolved import error for the below sample code. Can somebody help me to resolve this issue
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};
use std::cmp;

use rand::Rng;

fn write_random_data() {

}

fn main() {

}

Error
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rand`
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 | use rand::Rng;
  |     ^^^^ help: a similar path exists: `openssl::rand`

Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "dd_demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
openssl = "0.10.66"

[dev-dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"

If I move rand crate from [dev-dependencies] to [dependencies], it compiles successfully.

Dev-dependencies are not used when compiling a package for building, but are used for compiling tests, examples, and benchmarks.
